# How to make an HTML styled-link in IOS?

Tags: ios, nsurl

**Target**

Give the User a clickable link like they experience and expect from HTML

**HTML Example**

- [w3schools - Web Links Example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/exercise.asp?filename=exercise_links1)

**Question**

Is this possible from IOS? I have seen how to -

- apply an underline through NSMutableAttributedString
- how to open a link through UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")!);
- (todo) color
- (todo) color toggle

I really hope that this is! It is a strong desire of mine to add to my App right now!

Comment: show some code. what have you tried?

Comment: Can't you just add a borderless button?

Comment: A borderless button is my backup plan. It is a 50% solution, it gets you nearly there! I will post that answer here when complete!